# Elasticsearch is running, but can not connect to :9200 port

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I've set up Elasticsearch on OSX (Mavericks) about two months ago via `brew install`, things were working good.

Then I move to another project, run `brew update` once. The current elasticsearch version is `elasticsearch: 1.2.0`

When I run `elasticsearch --config=/usr/local/opt/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml` as `brew info` suggested, the service is starting as expected:

```
[2014-05-26 14:26:15,916][INFO ][node                     ] [Red Nine] version[1.2.0], pid[10747], build[c82387f/2014-05-22T12:49:13Z]
[2014-05-26 14:26:15,916][INFO ][node                     ] [Red Nine] initializing ...
[2014-05-26 14:26:15,921][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Red Nine] loaded [], sites []
[2014-05-26 14:26:17,947][INFO ][node                     ] [Red Nine] initialized
[2014-05-26 14:26:17,947][INFO ][node                     ] [Red Nine] starting ...
[2014-05-26 14:26:18,039][INFO ][transport                ] [Red Nine] bound_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9300]}
[2014-05-26 14:26:21,070][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Red Nine] new_master [Red Nine][EytfiY9TRtmihwuNF9SieQ][geckos-mbp][inet[/127.0.0.1:9300]], reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
[2014-05-26 14:26:21,093][INFO ][discovery                ] [Red Nine] elasticsearch_Gecko/EytfiY9TRtmihwuNF9SieQ
[2014-05-26 14:26:21,105][INFO ][http                     ] [Red Nine] bound_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9200]}
[2014-05-26 14:26:21,115][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Red Nine] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
[2014-05-26 14:26:21,115][INFO ][node                     ] [Red Nine] started
```

But when I try to `curl -XGET http://localhost:9200`, it's responding with 503 error.

There was once WARN in the log, but the start log is good as shown above:

```
[2014-05-26 13:04:22,192][WARN ][cluster.metadata         ] [Balder] [video_interviews_development_20140310134134379] re-syncing mappings with cluster state for types [[video_interview]]
[2014-05-26 13:04:22,193][WARN ][cluster.metadata         ] [Balder] [sections_development_20140310134135051] re-syncing mappings with cluster state for types [[section]]
[2014-05-26 13:04:22,193][WARN ][cluster.metadata         ] [Balder] [announcements_development_20140310134133810] re-syncing mappings with cluster state for types [[announcement]]
[2014-05-26 13:04:22,193][WARN ][cluster.metadata         ] [Balder] [articles_development_20140310134134125] re-syncing mappings with cluster state for types [[article]]
[2014-05-26 13:04:22,193][WARN ][cluster.metadata         ] [Balder] [courses_development_20140310134134846] re-syncing mappings with cluster state for types [[course]]
```

Can anyone help? thanks :)   It's okey to flush all data since only my local environment has this problem.

#### more info

- I haven't touched the elasticsearch.yml file
- tried `brew remove elasticsearch` and re-install, not working

Comment: /usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/0.1.2/config/elasticsearch.yml - try this path to the config file - maybe they changed some stuff from one update to the other - always use the version specific one

Comment: @marvwhere thanks for the tip, I've tried your suggesion, still 503 error sadly :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved.

It's the proxying service I used causing 503 error, turning it off and everything is okey :)